# Access to the url of a node from another one

Tags: nodes, rules

I'm a bit stuck there ! here what i do :

I have two content types : Ad Lock, Ad complete.
When a user create a node Ad Lock, i use rules to clone it and then convert the original in Ad complete.

So now i have two nodes in two different content types.

Now i need to copy the url of Ad complete to fill a field in Ad Lock. Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance guys !

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my mistake was : that i used a module called "url field" and it was not recognise by rule. With a normal text field i can copy the link i want